# Golang DB2 error

Tags: go, db2, odbc, db2-luw

I'm trying to connect to a db2 using golang using https://bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli. While trying to follow the instructions, I run into this error

```
vendor/bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/api/api_unix.go:12:11: fatal 
error: 'sqlcli1.h' file not found
#include <sqlcli1.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This is the script I tried to use

```
#!/bin/bash
DB2HOME=$HOME/sqllib
export CGO_LDFLAGS=-L$DB2HOME/lib
export CGO_CFLAGS=-I$DB2HOME/include

go install .
```

Could someone point me to what I need to do to use db2cli? I'm running this code on a macbook.

Comment: Which Db2-client is installed ?  What is result of `ls $DB2HOME/sqllib/inlcude/sqlcli*.h` ?  (should contain 2 files sqlcli1.h and sqlcli.h if you installed the correct Db2 product to allow the build to succeed).

Comment: I get `No such file or directory` when I run your command. To add more information, I don't have db2 installed on my local and I'm trying to access a remote db2 server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build golang with the phiggins db2cli , your workstation or server needs to have a Db2 product (e.g. a suitable client, or a server package) installed locally specifically to deliver the INCLUDE files and the library files for development with Db2.

The Db2-client software comes in different packages for different purposes, and a Db2-client also comes with a Db2-LUW server. For development purposes (i.e. to compile and link executable programs) you need the "IBM Data Server Driver package".

IBM describes the different Db2 client types at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html).

If your remote Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, you can also try building golang-db2cli on that hostname and copy the build-targets to your workstation provided the server and workstation run the same distro and bitness and release and that the Db2 version/fixpack is identical to that of the client.

Otherwise you can download and install the relevant package from IBM's Fix Central website (registration required) , or from IBM's Passport Advantage website for registered entitled customers. The Db2-client download links are available currently at this [link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217).

Answer (score 0):

The driver I was using was `github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db`, and I ended up solving the problem as follows:

import _ github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db

- go mod tidy
- go mod download
- cd $GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db@v0.4.2/installer
- sh setup.go

  This script will download db2cli to the `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/ibmdb` directory by default
- sh setenv.sh

  This script sets environment variables based on the current scenario, The key variables are: `CGO_CFLAGS`, `CGO_CFLAGS`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`(linux), `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`(mac)

Comment: I am getting below error
Failed to load db2cli64.dll: The specified module could not be found.
The go_ibm_db driver cannot be registered

Can you please help

Comment: You are windows operating system, download [ntx64_odbc_cli.zip](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip) , unzip and set the environment variables:

`set clidrvpath=%you unzip path%`  
`set IBM_DB_HOME=%clidrvpath%`  
`set PATH=%PATH%;%IBM_DB_HOME%\bin`